# Where I can find OpenJDK tests?

Tags: java

I am interested in how JDK is tested itself, what test engine it uses.

I found some links:

- https://github.com/ddopson/openjdk-test - does not look as official repository
- http://openjdk.java.net/jtreg/ - contains regression tests, points to [Jonathan Gibbons' blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/jjg/category/jtreg) but seems that it is unavailable

Also, I would like to see how frameworks like Swing and JavaFX are tested.

Are there any *manuals* / *instructions* available about how to *execute* / *look through* JDK tests?

Comment: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d ? There's also some documentation on how to build here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/build-infra/guide.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenJDK comes with its own regression test suite.

The tests can be found in the 'test' subdirectory of the individual repositories making up a JDK forest. For example, javax.swing jtreg tests for JDK 9 can be found at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/tip/test/javax/swing .

These tests are run using the jtreg tool. You can learn more about it here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jtreg/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the bulk of the tests is still run through `jtreg`.  The tests themselves are part of the OpenJDK source trees stored in Mercurial.

I'd look at distribution packaging for information how to run `jtreg`.  I think the distributions run at least a subset of the test suite as part of the build process.  I don't know anything in particular about GUI testing; I have never had the need to look at those.